# Foursquare api returning null access_token

Tags: php, foursquare

Im using a code of an answer here:

[Answer by BentFX](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6159809/connecting-with-foursquare-api-v2-using-php)

I am using wamp and I did everything as he did. The problem is that the $token value is empty. I wouldn't have asked but it is returning null and I tried almost everything.
 Here's the code:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>FourSquare test page...</title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<script type="text/javascript">
<!--
var foursquareKey;

// Open foursquare login window.
function get4sqKey(){
  if(!foursquareKey){
    window.open('scripts/4sq_Login.php', 'foursquareAuth', 'width=960, height=548');
  }
}

// called crosswindow by login window
function set4sqKey(key){
  foursquareKey = key;
  alert(foursquareKey);
  //alert("Logged into Foursquare"); // setTimeout makes alert non-blocking

}

// simple alert to display OAuth token
function showKey(){
  alert(foursquareKey);
}

// -->
</script>
</head>
<body>
<a href="javascript:get4sqKey();">get4sqKey();</a> |
<a href="javascript:showKey();">showKey();</a>
</body>
</html>
```

**4sq_login.php** in scripts folder.

```
<?php

  require_once('secrets.php'); //defines CLIENT_ID

// build $url
  $url = 'https://foursquare.com/oauth2/authenticate';
  $url .= '?client_id='.CLIENT_ID;
  $url .= '&response_type=code';
  $url .= '&redirect_uri=http://localhost/scripts/4sq_Callback.php'; 

  header( 'Location: '.$url ) ;

  ?>
```

**4sq_Callback.** The directories are set and the foursquare callback link is also correct.

```
<?php
// Foursquare login step 2, echo back $code from QUERY_STRING
  require_once('secrets.php'); // defines CLIENT_ID & CLIENT_SECRET

// get $code from QUERY_STRING
  parse_str($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'], $query);
  $code = $query['code'];

// build url
  $url2 = 'https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token';
  $url2 .= '?client_id='.CLIENT_ID;
  $url2.= '&client_secret='.CLIENT_SECRET;
  $url2 .= '&grant_type=authorization_code';
  $url2 .= '&redirect_uri=http://localhost/scripts/4sq_Callback.php'; //change to your 4sq callback
  $url2 .= "&code=.$code";

// call to https://foursquare.com/oauth2/access_token with $code
  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url2);
  $result = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);

// $result value is json {access_token: ACCESS_TOKEN}
  $values = json_decode($result, true);
  $token = $values['access_token'];

// set access_token cookie (if you wish)

// crosswindow scripting to pass back $token
  echo('<script type="text/javascript">');
  echo('opener.set4sqKey("'.$token.'");');
  echo('self.close();'); // close self
  echo('</script>');
```

Comment: What is the output of `var_dump($result)`?

Comment: Also, the line `$url2 .= "&code=.$code";` looks a little suspect...Unless this is a special format requirement of the API, did you mean `$url2 .= "&code=".$code;`

Comment: var_dump gives boolean false

Comment: No change my friend still boolean false

Comment: What about a `var_dump` on your `$code` variable? You want to make sure you are actually getting a code back. (No need to tell me what its value is, just that is what you would expect).

Comment: a code which I then exchange for token. Everything works fine until the line $ch = curl_init(); I think the script is not calling the url correctly but I dont know why. My wamp is configured correctly for the curl method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114662/discussion-between-fahad-rana-and-kunruh).

Answer (score 0):

I figured out. The problem was the cURL method was not working correctly.
I simply used this line to get the access token. I dont know why cURL is not working but this method is a working substitute:

```
$values= file_get_contents($url2);
```